# what will be the max size of allocated memory returned by i2c_get_dma_safe_msg_buf in linux subsystem?

Tags: linux-device-driver, i2c

I am looking for the answers/path forward for the size of buffer returned by the API `i2c_get_dma_safe_msg_buf()` in Linux subsystem?

Also I want to know what can be the max size of the buffer which can be allocated to `i2c_msg->buf`?

Please help because I am not getting answers from the internet.

Comment: Are you able to read the code: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core-base.c#L2582? You can do your homework work and easily answer to your question (takes 5 to 15 minutes).

Comment: The maximum size is `KMALLOC_MAX_SIZE` defined by `#include <linux/slab.h>`, which is probably 4194304 bytes (4 MiB).

Comment: Maybe better ask at [Linux & UNIX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out also by looking at kernel code. It states the same as (4 MiB)